# Sublevels in Drop Down Menu Stack on top of One Another Instead of Displaying Verticly

Tags: html, css

Recently a few months ago I had to add sublevel functionality into a drop down menu on one of our sites. The tactic I took before worked well for the one column in the navigation, but I was asked to add a sublevel to the column before it which didn't work because I was using relative positioning (see the example below):

```
<style type="text/css">
#div#mycontent { overflow: visible; }
#nav ul { font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 10px; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-weight: bold; }
#nav ul li { display: block; float: left; margin: 0;}
#nav li ul { display: none; }
#nav ul li a { display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #3c1c4e; border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px; background: #f0e8d8; margin-left: 1px; white-space: nowrap; }
#nav ul li a:hover { background: #f0e8d8; }
#nav li:hover ul { display: block; position: absolute; }
#nav li:hover li { float: none; font-size: 11px; }
#nav li:hover a { background: #f0e8d8; }
#nav li:hover li a:hover { background: #fff7e7; }
```

/* This is for sublevels in the drop down */
    #nav li:hover ul li ul {display: none}
    #nav li ul li:hover ul { display: block; }
    #nav li ul li ul li { position: relative; left: 188px; bottom:25px ;padding-left:1px }

So I modified the sublevels in the drop down menu to use relative positioning used an overlap approach (due to the way to previous coder originally designed the drop down). The new code looks like the one below:

```
#nav li ul li ul li { position: absolute; left: 125px; bottom: 0px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color:purple; z-index: 1; }
```

However as the title indicates the LI under the unordered list are now stacking on top of one another. Instead of displaying vertically one after the other. I believe it requires me to clear the float, but it looks like it was done up above. So I'm unsure if I need to redefine the float then clear it in order to make sure the links in the sub list will display vertically.

Edit:

A good thought to add the HTML to show how I'm trying to execute this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#div#mycontent { overflow: visible; }
#nav ul { font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 10px; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-weight: bold; }
#nav ul li { display: block; float: left; margin: 0;}
#nav li ul { display: none; }
#nav ul li a { display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #3c1c4e; border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px; background: #f0e8d8; margin-left: 1px; white-space: nowrap; }
#nav ul li a:hover { background: #f0e8d8; }
#nav li:hover ul { display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 0;}
#nav li:hover li { float: none; font-size: 11px; }
#nav li:hover a { background: #f0e8d8; }
#nav li:hover li a:hover { background: #fff7e7; }
/* This is for sublevels in the drop down */
#nav li:hover ul li ul {display: none}
#nav li ul li:hover ul { display: block; }
#nav li ul li ul li { position: absolute; left: 125px; bottom: 0px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color:purple; z-index: 1; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Column 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Column 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Column 3</a><li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) as well ..

Comment: Tried adding my code and it didn't result anything. Doesn't use JavaScript to accomplish this just HTML and CSS. I added the HTML code to the original post.

Comment: here is the http://jsfiddle.net/wukdU/

Comment: This is more closer to what I'm trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/wukdU/2/


You can see the sublinks are stacking instead of displaying vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these CSS rules for your sublevels in the drop down:

```
/* This is for sublevels in the drop down */
     #nav li:hover ul li ul {
        display: none
    }
    #nav li ul li:hover ul {
        display: block;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:100%;
    }
    #nav li ul li ul li {
        position:relative;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid purple;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much that got me past the issue of them stacking. Its lining up incorrectly now but I think I can take it from there :)